# How to filter similar URLS located in a list of values nested in a dictionary?

Tags: python

How can I alter the below code to filter out similar URLs?

examples of duplicates:

```
http://www.example.com/sunshine

https://example.com/sunshine

https://www.example.com/sunshine_
```

---

```
result = {}

for key,value in student_data.items():
    if value not in result.values():
        result[key] = value

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to come up with a precise definition of what you mean by 'similar'. Looking at your examples, it looks like you want to do the following:

1. Ignore the part before '//'
2. Ignore presence or absence of 'www.'
3. Ignore any trailing underscores

You can define a function to standardize URLs by removing these parts. You can edit this function later if you want to add any conditions to your definition.

Once you've done so, you can standardize every item in the list and then look for only unique items to see how many 'unique' URLs you have after standardizing. Something like the following:

```
urls = [
    'http://www.example.com/sunshine',
    'https://example.com/sunshine',
    'https://www.example.com/sunshine_'
]

def standardize(url):

    # Discard everything before '//'
    url = url.partition('//')[2]
    # Strip 'www.' from beginning or end
    url = url.strip('www.')
    # Strip '_' from beginning or end
    url = url.strip('_')
    return url

# Standardize every url in the list
standardized = [standardize(url) for url in urls]
# Remove duplicates
unique = list(set(standardized))
for u in unique:
    print(u)
```

Output:

```
example.com/sunshine
```